# Symfony 3.1 Forms with lookup table and multiple choices save options (3 tables)

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

My question is related to **building Forms** out of these tables, as I am stuck at creating the forms using *Symfony 3.1.1*. I have these 3 tables namely User, User2Pref and Preference (I hope their relations are self explanatory). I created the equivalent Entities, which I have also included in the next sections.

```
======================== 
|         User         | 
|======================| 
| id | Fname  | Lname  |  Profile Table
| 1  | Tom    | Cat    | 
| 2  | Jerry  | Rat    | 
----------------------- 

======================== 
|       User2Pref      | 
|======================| 
| U.id | P.id |  Tag   |  Mapping Table
|   1  |   2  |   a    |  Tag is optional
|   2  |   3  |   b    | 
------------------------ 

========================
|         Pref         | 
|----------------------| 
|  id |  Prop  |  Grp  |  Properties Table
|  1  |  Wht   |  Col  |  Can be grouped, or have more
|  2  |  Blk   |  Col  |  columns (properties)
|  3  |  Abc   |  Xyz  | 
------------------------
```

User entity:

```
class User {
    ....
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserPreferenceMapping", mappedBy="user")
     *
     */
     pritected theMappings;
     ....
}
```

UserToPref entity:

```
class UserToPref {
    ....
    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Preference
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Preference", inversedBy="theMappings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="preference_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
     private $preference;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="theMappings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
     private $user;

     ....
 }
```

Preference entity:

```
class Property {    
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserPreferenceMapping", mappedBy="preference")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="preference_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     *
     */
    protected $theMappings;
}
```

For the *formTypes*, I have created: UserType, UserToPrefType and PropertyType classes. I was able to create the form but only *in parts* so it was not much of help. I want to pull out the different options from Preference table and be able to save one/or/multiple values for [A]. A new form, [B]. Edit form. Can anyone help me please?

**Details added: #1**

====== My Forms and Controllers ======

This is my UserType form: (prototype)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('fname')
        ->add('lname')

        ->add('favColours', ChoiceBoxType:class,

        /* I want to show here all choice of colours from Preferences table and let user choose none/one/multi. 
         * What I tried: fetching them from database directly using query builder, I could show options inside choicebox
        */
        )

        ->add('favHobbies', 
        /* similar as above this time hobbies from Preferences table */
        )

        ->add('moreOptions', 
        /* similar as above with more options from Preferences table */
        )

        /* and so on */
}
```

And in AddNew controller, I begin with:

```
public function newAction(Request $request) {

    $pref = new Preference();
    $maps = new User2Pref();

    /* NEED HELP TO INIT USER2PREF AND PREFERENCE OBJECTS FOR USER */

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /* NEED HELP HERE TO PERSIST SUBMITTED DATA INTO User2Pref */
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Similarly inside Edit controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request) {

    $pref = new Preference();
    $maps = new User2Pref();

    /* NEED HELP TO LOAD EXISTING VALUES FROM User2Pref AND PREFERENCE */

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /* NEED HELP HERE TO PERSIST SUBMITTED DATA INTO User2Pref */
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that, addNew form can show options but I don't know how to persist them upon submission. Similarly can't load the saved options either. Need help! :o

**Details added #2**

====== Open for alternatives ======

I can drop the idea of User2Pref table if it is more simpler to achieve requirements. Attached below is the idea in pictorial representation. *Green* is User's native form field, *White* dropdown are choices from Preferences table (meaning they are fixed/specific and are none/multi select), Blue: Could be something that can be added by user on the fly.

[image: Requirements]

I will then have ManyToMany relationships between User and Preference which I understand. Can you give me hints on how I can achieve this goal from inside the controller?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how the final form should look like? Now the description of what you're trying to do is not clear to me. Also you could provide what you have tried and tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: @dragoste: Thank you for your comment. I have added more details now. I want to save chosen options to User2Pref table for a selected User and Preference(s) pair. Suggestions?

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now. You have single collection of `Preferences` in `User` but you want to split this into a few form fields by `Preference::group`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly, and I want to be able to save them into User2Pref table like I mentioned in my question. Can you me show me how? :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do that. Just to mention a few:

- custom `PreferenceCollectionType` containing fields handling `Preference`s, that would have to utilize a [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) that would convert whole collection of `Preference` entities to a few smaller collections grouped by `Preference::grp` property (or whatever its name is). And a reverse transformer for vice versa operation of course (merging sub collections into single one).
- create separate many-to-many fields in User for every group utilizing [STI](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) on `Preference` by creating subclasses for each group. That is actually possible to do without [STI](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance), but you will be responsible to keep an eye on cohesion of data.
- *simulate* existence of these separate collections of `Preference` by only implementing appropriate setters and getters on `User` class. Then the form will think that there are such properties.

I won't provide you ready solution because I don't know which one you need and anyway it's not trivial enough to write it here without running in real code.

**EDIT:**
Since you're using manyToOne + oneToMany instead of manytoMany, the second solution with STI may be hard to implement.

Comment: I trust experts! I added some more details. I am pretty sure you have the right solution for me.